# Inconsistent st_blocks and st_size values for inaccessible file

Tags: stat

I have a small text file (some metadata redacted)

```
-rw-r--r--  1 ****  ****  17198 Sep 29  2019 230999.txt
```

But it can't be viewed

```
% cat 230999.txt
cat: 230999.txt: Attribute not found
```

I'm not sure what attribute is missing. It's a simple text file. `cp` and `mv` return the same error.

Stat shows `st_blocks` and `st_size` values that don't seem consistent:

```
% stat -f 'st_size=%z st_blocks=%b st_blksize=%k' 230999.txt
st_size=17198 st_blocks=0 st_blksize=4096
```

Everything I've read relates `st_size` and `st_blocks` usually using `st_blksize`. This tells me the file size but says there are no blocks allocated to it.

How do I access this file?

Update in response to comment:

I am unfamiliar with `strace` so I did the following:

```
sudo dtruss cat 230999.txt
...
open("230999.txt\0", 0x0, 0xFFFFFFFFE4CFABE5)        = -1 Err#2
write_nocancel(0x2, "cat: \004\b\0", 0x5)        = 5 0
write_nocancel(0x2, "230999.txt\b\0", 0xA)       = 10 0
write_nocancel(0x2, ": \b\0", 0x2)       = 2 0
write_nocancel(0x2, "No such file or directory\n\b\0", 0x1A)         = 26 0
close_nocancel(0x1)
```

(Left as an update since comments destroyed formatting)

Comment: Have you run `fsck` on that volume? If so, add the output of `strace cat 230999.txt` (only the last lines before the error) to your question.

Comment: On what type of filesystem is the file located?

Comment: This is a Mac running the most recent version of 10.15.

Comment: `sudo fsck_hfs -fl /dev/disk6s1` says the volume is okay.